# django admin delete objects in inlines in save_model method

Tags: django, admin, inlines, validationerror

I have two related (via foreignkey relation) models and created admin model for parent with inlines. In several cases (edited in admin by boolean field), i need to delete all previous objects (inlines) and create new ones. I've tried to make it with save_model, where i can get all current object's properties and decide if i need to recreate (inline) objects.
models:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    reformat = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = ForeignKey(Model1, related_name='model2')
    ...
```

admin:

```
class Model2Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model2

class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [Model2Inline]
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(Model1Admin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        if obj.reformat:
            obj.model2.all().delete()
            # creating new objects
            ...
        obj.save()
```

But if i try to delete these objects in model_save method i get ValidationError.
Is there other possibilities to solve this problem?

Comment: `ValidationError` isn't being raised from there. Do you have a `clean` method on your models? If so, post that code as well. Otherwise, your code is getting hung up before it even gets to `save_model` so post any forms you're using.

Comment: No there is no clean() method defined. i decided that problem is there because if i comment line with delete(), it works as expected, but it saves previous objects as well (that i don't want).

Comment: i decided to try signals instead. Make some changes in admin model with save_model method and main part of processing store in pre_save or post_save signal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came across this problem as well, and, after an hour or two of banging my head against the wall, solved it by overriding `save_formset()` on the admin object instead of `save_model()` and doing the required manipulation after calling the super class's `save_formset()` method. Doing it this way means the models which you are deleting are still present when the formset is saved, so you don't get the validation error.

Here's what it might look like in the example you gave:

```
class Model2Inline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model2

class Model1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [Model2Inline]
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        super(Model1Admin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
        if formset.model is Model2:
            obj = formset.instance
            if obj.reformat:
                obj.model2.all().delete()
                # creating new objects
                ...
            obj.save()
```

Comment: I had to remove the 'self' in 'save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change)'